# How to limit the number of active Tasks running via the Parallel Task Library?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have some ConcurrentQueue that contain Action ( System.Action ).
Each action in this queue need to run ( need to be called by using invoke ).

When the queue is not empty => the action need to be invoke => But i want to make some limit on the number of the parallel task that will run.
Beside this, A new action can be added to the queue any time.

How to do it ?

( using .net 4.0 )

I wrote something but i not sure this is the best approach

```
 SemaphoreSlim maxThread = new SemaphoreSlim(5);

 while( !actionQueue.IsEmpty )
        {
            maxThread.Wait();
            Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
            {
                Action action;
                if( actionExecution.TryDequeue( out action) )
                {
                    action.Invoke();
                }
            },
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning ).ContinueWith( ( task ) => maxThread.Release() );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the real problem?  Why do you feel the need to limit the number of tasks?

Comment: just academic experience .. i want to learn. but i also want to know why i don't need to make this limit ?

Comment: There is no need to limit the number of tasks - I see now you're talking about *concurrently executing* tasks and not the total number in the queue; lazyberezovsky's answer below is the correct one for this scenario.

Comment: Take a look at TPL dataflow, depending on you're scenario it can act like a great fit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look on MSDN article [How to: Create a Task Scheduler That Limits Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx). You can use `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` implementation from it to make your code like this:

```
var scheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(5);
TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);

while( !actionQueue.IsEmpty )
{
    factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        Action action;
        if(actionExecution.TryDequeue(out action))                
            action.Invoke();

    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

Comment: Why is this better than the solution that the OP suggested using SemaphoreSlim?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to specify ParallelOptions

```
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;//value of your choice

if (Parallel.ForEach(PDFFiles, options, element =>
{
   //do work 
}
```